# Implode string and insert into array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, random

I can't get the implode function to work with my array. I'm building a site and every time you reload the page the background image is randomly chosen.

**I have a loop with different image url:s like this:**

```
<?php 
if( have_rows('pictures', 'option') ):
    while ( have_rows('pictures', 'option') ) : the_row();
        $pictures[] = get_sub_field('picture'); 
        $picturesimploded = "'" . implode("', '", $pictures) . "'";
    endwhile;
endif; 
?>
```

**Below is the code to randomize which url is chosen:**

```
<?php   
    $bg = array( $picturesimploded ); // array of filenames
    $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
    $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
```

**The url is then applied to a div:**

```
<div style="background-image: url( <?php echo $selectedBg; ?> );">
```

**The output however prints all links:**

```
<div style="background-image: url( 'http://example.com/image1', 'http://example.com/image1', 'http://example.com/image1' );">
```

It seems like the array can't separate the arrays. When I insert the links manually, directly, in the array like this it works:

```
<?php   
    $bg = array( 'http://example.com/image1', 'http://example.com/image1', 'http://example.com/image1' ); // array of filenames
    $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
    $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
```

Any ideas how to get the randomizing to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
$bg = array( $picturesimploded );
```

with

```
$bg = explode( $picturesimploded );
```

-- when you call

```
$bg = array( $picturesimploded );
```

you are making an array with one entry like this:

```
[0] => 'image,image,image,image,image'
```

when you use explode it will be like this

```
[0] => image,
[1] => image,
```

etc

an alternative would be to do this:

```
<?php 
$pictures = array();
if( have_rows('pictures', 'option') ):
    while ( have_rows('pictures', 'option') ) : the_row();
        $pictures[] = get_sub_field('picture'); 
    endwhile
endif; 

$i = rand(0, count($pictures)-1); // generate random number size of the array
$selectedBg = $pictures[$i]; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen


?>
```

Comment: Your alternative way looks great! Is there a way of using `wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, $image_size);` instead of  `get_sub_field('picture');`? I can't get it to work, and I assume the setup doesn't work with wp_get_attachment_image_src?

Comment: I use 
wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail'); -- but I'm not sure how you could work it into your code

Answer (score 1):

- flip the array to work on values.
- use array_rand with 1 to get 1 random element
- Example: http://ideone.com/cpV2Va

  ```
  <?php

  $pictures = array();
  if( have_rows('pictures', 'option') ):
      while ( have_rows('pictures', 'option') ) : the_row();
         $pictures[] = get_sub_field('picture'); 
      endwhile
  endif; 

  $selectedBg = array_rand(array_flip($pictures), 1);
  ```